Gas dryer to electric with capped gas line question
I had a gas dryer that was old and just made me nervous. I just replaced with a new electric one because I had the correct outlet for electricity. I had a plumber cap the gas line and an electrician turn on the breaker for electricity as it was turned off prior.
The old gas dryer was connected with a long gas line that sticks out of the wall. It was just capped so it still protrudes. The new dryer sits close to it and the dryer vent tubbing is right next to it.
If you couldn’t tell gas makes me very nervous. Is my new dryer going to be safe to use?

didn't the old dryer sit close to the gas line?

Is your worry about someone/something snagging the gas line stub?

Yes. If the plumber did the job properly, the gas isn’t leaking at all and there is no danger to having the pipe there.

I've been living with exactly that setup  for about 14 years now. I have considered taking out that gas line entirely, but that would just mean capping it farther back toward the meter, since I'm still using gas for hot water and have the radiators available as a backup heating system. If you're worried, then have a gas fitter wave a sniffer around the pipe, which should be able to detect even at low-level leakage.
